# Why is my code repeating when it shouldn't?

Tags: python

```py
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
num = int(input("Pick a number between 1-10 "))
while num != str(list):
    print("That is not an adaquate choice.")
    num = int(input("Pick a number between 1-10 "))
    if num == 1:
        file = open("external_files.txt", "w")
        hsname = input("Please enter your name. If it is over 5 letters, use your initials. ")
        if len(hsname) < 5:
            print("Your name has been added to the scoreboard.")
            file.write("\n")
            file.write(hsname)
            file.write(" - ")
            file.write(str(x))
            file.close()
        else:
            while len(hsname) > 5:
                print("Sorry, that name is too long.")
                hsname = input("Please enter your name. If it is over 5 letters, use your initials. ")
                if len(hsname) < 5:
                    print("Your name has been added to the scoreboard.")
                    file.write("\n")
                    file.write(hsname)
                    file.write(" - ")
                    file.write(str(x))
                    file.close()
                    break
```

This is only a little bit of the code to not bore you with repetetiveness, but the loop does break under the right condidtions.

My problem is that, further down in the code, it is mostly the same but without the `while` and other statements that would deny it from making sense if I enter a number that is not in that list. But when I run it it contstantly says "That is not an adaquate choice."

Comment: @Mike67, Thank you so much!

Comment: `while num != str(list):`  Simply print the values you're comparing, and you'll see one fatal problem.  This is standard debugging.

Comment: your indenting is wrong and way to large, 2,3 or 4 spaces

Answer (score 0):

`str(list)` is returning the entire list as a single string which will never match the input.

Change this line:

```
while num != str(list):
```

To this:

```
while not num in list:
```

As a side note, you should not use `list` as a variable name since it is a type in Python.